# Template member function overloading issue

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, overloading

The Standard at `N4296::13.1/2.2 [over.load]` says:

> Likewise, member function template declarations with the same name,
>   the same parameter-type-list, and the same template parameter lists
>   cannot be overloaded if any of them is a static member function
>   template declaration.

So, I thought that the following program would be ill-formed:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    template <typename T>
    static void foo(){ }

    template <typename T>
    static int foo(){ return 0; }
};

int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dff9a898926c3cf5)**

In contrast, the program

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    static void foo(){ }

    static int foo(){ return 0; }
};

int main(){ }
```

is ill-formed

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01a51d7ed1f3d284)**

Is the first example a bug?

Comment: @T.C. I meant the functions were static. In the demo they were.

Comment: Yes, it's ill-formed, and the failure to diagnose it is a compiler bug.

Comment: Try to instantiate any of those and compiler will report a problem. I would guess it passes definition check (1st stage lookup), but during instantiation in 2nd stage lookup overload resolution will catch the error. GCC does it on instantiation

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux No, the program should be ill-formed even if the name are not odr-used.

Comment: Which compiler(s) are failing to diagnose the first example?

Answer (score 1):

Currently subject of [**CWG #1252**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1252):

> The Standard does not allow overloading of member functions that
>   differ only in their return type (cf `enable_if`).

The wording you quoted is presumably going to be amended, since there is no reason whatsoever to disallow overloading of member function templates based on SFINAE in the return type; I'd regard the standard as defective and the implementations as correct.

Comment: Seems that it will be fixed in C++23 thanks to the "Declarations and where to find them" paper.

Comment: @BrianBi Didn't find the relevant spot over a quick glance, can you show where? (I do think it likely does to be clear)

Comment: [basic.scope.scope]/4 introduces the definition of when two declarations *correspond*. If both declarations are of function templates, they only correspond when their signatures correspond. Under [defns.signature.member.templ], member functions of class templates have the return type as part of the signature.